# Read first character of string as integer in C

Tags: c, string, atoi

How would I go about reading the first character of this string as an integer?

```
char *p = argv[1];
```

Thank you!

Comment: Have a look at the atoi function

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your question is ambiguous.  Here are three possible interpretations and their answers.

1. Every character of a "string" in C is in fact a small integer, which you can retrieve by simply indexing the array.

   ```
   int first = p[0];
   ```
2. If you know that the first character of the string is a digit and you want its value *as a digit*, you can take advantage of the fact that the character codes for `'0'` through `'9'` are guaranteed to be contiguous and increasing:

   ```
   int first_dv = -1;
   if (p[0] >= '0' && p[0] <= '9')
       first_dv = p[0] - '0';
   ```
3. If you misspoke, and you actually want to process the *whole string* as a decimal number, you do that with `strtol`, or `strtoul` if the number should never be interpreted as negative:

   ```
   char *endp;
   errno = 0;
   long numeric_value = strtol(p, &endp, 10);
   if (endp == p || *endp) {
       fprintf(stderr, "junk after number: %s\n", endp);
   } else if (errno) {
       fprintf(stderr, "%s: invalid number (%s)\n", p, strerror(errno));
   }
   ```

   These are declared in `<stdlib.h>`.  You do *not* do this with `atoi` or `sscanf`, contra what many other people will tell you: `atoi` won't tell you if there was junk after the number, and `sscanf` not only won't tell you that, it is allowed to crash your program on numeric overflow.

Comment: He also used the name argv which could mean he is talking about arguments which is a 2d array.